# Connection Between Tochacha and Evaluating People (Arechin)

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rebuke-tochacha, bechukosai, hekdesh

Immediately after the long Tochacha of Bechukosai ([Vayikra 26:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), the Torah continues with Arechin (Vayikra 27)- evalutating people's value in money to be consecrated for the Mishkan/Beis HaMikdash. What is the connection between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The Abarbenel in the name of the Ramban (and the Tur Haaroch and Ramban commentaries) says:

> מפני שהחמירה התורה בשמירת השמטות והיובלים ויעדה שיבא גלות לעולם על בטולם לכן הביא המצוות האלה מיד אחרי התוכחות להיותם במשפטי היובל כמו שהזכיר במקדיש שדה מקנה ושדה אחוזה. אלא שכלל משפטי כל הנידרים בפרשה אחת וכמו שכתב הרמב"ן
>   Since the Torah was very strict on keeping the *Shmita* (7th fallow) year and *Yovel*  (Jubilee), and specified the punishment of exile from the land of Israel because of not keeping the *Shmita* and *Yovel*, therefore these Mitzvos were enumerated after the *Tochacha*, on the laws of Yovel as mentioned "if someone buys a field and makes it *hekdesh* (property of the Beis Hamikdash) it should go back to its original owner on Yovel" so too all laws of vows and consecrations for *hekdesh* including value of individual pledges *Arachin* are mentioned all together after the Tochacha to remind people to guard laws of Yovel and *Shmitta*.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hirsch seems to understand that there’s no specific connection between Arachin and the Tochacha. Rather, the Sefer up to this point focuses on one general concept, while these last passages, beginning with Arachin, are fundamentally different – hence their position at the end, almost as an afterthought. In his own words (as [translated by Feldheim](https://www.feldheim.com/the-hirsch-chumash)):

> The book of Vayikra teaches us our duty to the Sanctuary of the Torah. We are to symbolize through offerings and to realize in practice the sanctification of our lives as individuals and as a nation. And, finally, the preceding chapter states that the חוקים משפטים ותורות — which tell us what we must do in order to hallow our lives as individuals and as a nation — are the sole intermediaries of the covenant between ourselves and God, and the sole means for assuring our welfare.
>
> Scripture now adds a concluding chapter on voluntary donations to the Sanctuary. A person feels the need or has the desire to give to the Sanctuary an object or its equivalent value, in order to demonstrate his special interest in the Sanctuary, or to signify the special relationship that — in his view — exists between the object and the Sanctuary.
>
> These donations to the Sanctuary are called here הפלאת נדר (v. 2 כי יפליא נדר). They are not required by law, and do not stem from the requirements of the law. Rather, they spring purely from one’s own feelings.
>
> It is characteristic that this chapter, which deals with donations to the Sanctuary, appears — by its position — merely as a supplementary concluding chapter. Scripture thus explicitly states that this chapter is not included among the חוקים משפטים ותורות, which God has set as the condition בינו ובין בני ישראל, and whose fulfillment will result in the fullness of blessing, and whose violation will bring about all the misery described in the preceding chapter. The donations to the Sanctuary are clearly separated from the חוקים משפטים ותורות, and this teaches us an important point:
>
> תורת כהנים, the Jewish priestly code, does not attach special value to Sanctuary donations, and does not see in them special piety, especially pleasing to God. Certainly, then, it does not ascribe to them the power to atone for a sinful life. The Sanctuary of the כהנים sees its mission not in gaining possessions, but in gaining hearts and souls. It seeks to gain the whole of our lives — as individuals and as a nation — for the fulfillment of the חוקים, the משפטים, and the תורות. The sanctification of morality, the safeguarding of justice in society, the enlightenment of the mind and the ennoblement of the heart — the חוקים, the משפטים, and the תורות — they are the sole means of attaining God’s grace. It is they that mediate בינו ובין בני ישראל, and only they bring man closer to God, and God closer to man.

Answer (score 1):

See the Kli Yakar:

> איש כי יפליא נדר וגו'. **סמך פר' זו לקללות לומר שישראל נודרים בעת צרה
>   כיעקב שהיה נודר בעת צרה ליתן מעשר מכל**, אבל לא כיעקב מכל וכל כי יעקב גם
>   אחר שעברה הצרה לא סר מן הדרך הטוב, אבל לדורות זה דרכם כסל למו שנודרים
>   בעת צרה ובעבור סופה צרה וצוקה הם מתחרטים ושבים לסורם וזה כמשל הקנה
>   שקלל בו אחיה השילוני את ישראל (מלכים א' יד טו) כי הקנה הזה אינו נכנע
>   כי אם בזמן שהרוח נושב בו וכנוח הרוח הוא חוזר ועומד בקומה זקופה
>   כבראשונה, כך ישראל אינן נכנעים כי אם בזמן שהצרה משמשת וירא ישראל כי
>   היתה הרוחה והכבד את לבו כי בסור המכריח ישובו לסורם, ומסכים לדברינו מה
>   שפירש בעל הטורים (כז א) שכל מספר השקלים קמ"ג כנגד קמ"ג קללות שבתורת
>   כהנים ובמשנה תורה (עיין מדרש תדשא אוצר המדרשים ע' 480), וכי מפני
>   שמספרם שוה נסמכו להדדי, אלא לומר לך שקמ"ג קללות שבתוכחה גורמין נדרי
>   קמ"ג שקלים כי אין ישראל נודרים ליתן מן ממונם לשם ה' כי אם בשעה שהצרות
>   מכריחין אותן, כמו שיתבאר בע"ה לקמן פרשת וילך (לא יז) על פסוק והיה כי
>   תמצאן אותו רעות רבות וצרות. שדרשו רז"ל (חגיגה ה.) על המלוה לעני בשעת
>   דחקו, ודרש זה רחוק לקבלו שכל הצרות לא יכריחום אל הוידוי כי אם צרה זו,
>   על כן רצוני לפרש שזה מדבר במלוה לעני בבא הצרה דווקא דהיינו בשעת דחקו
>   של המלוה כי הצרות דוחקין אותו לזה לידור נדרים לצדקה, וטעות של הנודר על
>   זה האופן יתבאר בעזרת ה' לקמן פר' וילך, על כן סמך פרשת כי יפליא לפרשת
>   התוכחה ודבר הכתוב בהווה. אבל כל מה שהאדם עושה בלא הכרח מרצון זהו נקרא
>   יום רצון לה' (ישעיה נח ה) ויפק רצון מה' (משלי ח לה).    תם ספר ויקרא -
>   בעזרת האל הגדול הגבור והנורא.

The Kli Yakar says that the Parsha of Arachin is juxtaposed to the Parsha of the Klalos because the Jewish people are emulating the actions of Yaakov Avinu, who made pledges when he found himself in difficult times.

---

I would like to suggest my own idea (based on the Kli Yakar above). The Torah details the laws of Arachin directly after the tochechas to remind us that, though hearing all the curses can be overwhelming and daunting, we must remember that we all have an inherent worth in the eyes of Hashem.